# SQL Server connection issue with Apache/Xampp

Tags: sql-server, server, xampp, windows-server

I am having an issue since I started my game and web.

I am hosting a game on a windows server, and also there is a SQL server installed (2008 management studio and all the other things...) because the game uses Databases from there, all works perfectly

For web, I am using XAMPP 1.7.3 and PHP 5.3.1 so that MSSQL works perfectly, and indeed it does.

web+game working perfect, mssql working perfect, all good, no errors

**BUT** my issue is now that after 1-2h (every 1-2h, not only 1x, means regularly) the MSSQL connection is lost of the web ... here a screen of the error:

it happens 1x after 1-2h and when it happens only restarting XAMPP apache helps to resolve the error, and it will immediately work again

MSSQL logs, apache logs everything is empty .. I really have no idea why this is happening since the beginning... I really have a hardcore headache for 3 days because I am not able to solve it

i hope really someone can help me or give me suggestions on that
I am even ready to pay for that :(

ps: I can only say that the game continues and doesn't lose the MSSQL connection, so it means there is no issue in MSSQL itself .. because otherwise, the game would die either but it is just the web which dies every 1-2h, only restarting apache helps

but it is really annoying because the player can't log in or do anything (because need web for it), please help me on that :/

Maybe it some wrong configuration? I really don't know ... I tried so much even my firewall etc. is off .... and it happens regularly every 1-2h but not the same time like not 1h 1h 1h maybe 1h 30 min 1h 20 min 2h 10 min, etc ...

thank you!

error screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHahS.png

Comment: sorry i mean i have all that full package i am using ODBC etc. for the game to connect to it and so on .. so its full package, because the web is working, it is just that every 1-2h it does not as said below thank you for that fast reply edit: i dont see your reply anymore whoever did post before O_O

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer to provide the information you put in the comment so that people who can assist you can find all relevant information in the question.

Comment: Try to connect to sql server using management studio. Then just type sp_who2 and execute. Check how many sessions you have. In case, when you reach a lot of sessions(dont remember, maybe ~1000), server begins to drop connections. Its only one of possible cases. Other research you can do: run sql server profiler or extended events and check or calls to server occurs

Comment: hello juozas i really dont know where to type this and 1000 sessions is alot for my player amount but maybe possible after 2h not sure, if every visit is counted as 1 session maybe, can u tell me where to do tha exactly and how to change the limit, actually this makes sense as i said it happens regularly but also different times so it must be something that "reaches" something .. thank you!

Comment: Just start sql server management studio, connect to server. Then press new query. Type sp_who2, and run command (you can use F5 fot it). You will be listed with all server sessions

Comment: here is my result: http://prntscr.com/kvv759 sorry didnt saw you edit ur msg hehe thx

Comment: thats alot lower than 1000 if 84 is the answer

Comment: Its normal, so problem somewhere else. You can try to check, or server see calls using sql server profiler: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2040/use-sql-server-profiler-to-trace-database-calls-from-third-party-applications/

Comment: @Juozas when the mssql in web wont work anymore (same as the error in the screen) i should see what was the last query to execute, to find the issue, or am i wrong?

Comment: It depends on situation, but at most cases youre right. If you see call to sql server, you can copy call and execute same statement using management studio. In this way you can analyze problem, or you remote call gives exception

Comment: @Juozas it just happened again this is the last entries: http://prntscr.com/kvxgwa i dont see an error its all completed, so what to do now :(?

Comment: i realised when it "lost connection" this came in apache log of xampp: [Wed Sep 19 02:41:19 2018] [error] [client 49.146.6.173] File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/function.mssql-connect, referer: editwebsitelink .. but i dont understand what that shall mean there is no file included with that name lol

Comment: always when this error came the connection was lost .. but i dont understand this error ...

Comment: Possibly problem is not on sql server side. As your last call to server returned no exception, application crashed later, when processing further steps. Maybe when processing received from sql server data. So, looks like I cannot help anymore, as it is out of sql server scope :)

Comment: hello, you cant even say something about the xampp error? because this is the reason for the "disconnect" :/